# Jquery event Span on click does not work

Tags: jquery, html

anybody can help me in getting no result value in onClick event when we click on Span that contain a text, seem it does not trigger an action..

```
$("#divResult").bind("click",function(e){ 
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      var $did = $clicked.find('.did').html();
      var $dname = $clicked.find('.dname').html();
      var decoded1 = $("<div/>").html($did).text();
      var decoded2 = $("<div/>").html($dname).text();
      $('#driverID').val(decoded1);
      $('#driverName').val(decoded2);
});
```

i already write on:

http://jsfiddle.net/mWWur/

Comment: Triggers the action fine for me

Comment: You did wrap it in `$(document).ready(...)`, right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Click on span is triggered, event target is span..

Comment: i just want to click on text inside by span even we click on #divResult, below as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `e.target` is not the div, but one of the `span`-s already. You have to modify your script

```
if ( e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "span" ) {
    var $clicked = $( e.target.parentNode );
} else {
    var $clicked = $( e.target );
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mWWur/2/)